# Return a List from database within a Servlet

Tags: sql, list, jsp, servlets, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to return a list from my database, but without JSTL and through this way (by adding some html in the servlet itself. It's for my school task). Here is my code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            Connection conexao = (Connection) new ConexaoFactory().getConnection();
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            PreparedStatement estrutura = conexao
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TB_MOVTIN_CLIENTE");
            
            ResultSet resultadoDados = estrutura.executeQuery();
            while(resultadoDados.next()) {
                cliente.setId(resultadoDados.getInt("ID_CLIENTE"));
                cliente.setNome(resultadoDados.getString("NOME"));
                request.setAttribute("message",
                                "<h1>Retorno da seleção</h1>" 
                                + "<table border=1> "
                                + "<tr> "
                                + "<td>Identificação</td>"
                                + "<td>Nome</td> " 
                                + "</tr>" 
                                + "<tr> "
                                + "<td>" + cliente.getId() + "</td>" 
                                + "<td>" + cliente.getNome() + "</td>" 
                                + " </tr> </table>");
            }
            resultadoDados.close();
            estrutura.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print("Erro: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("selecionaCliente.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific on the question.
**1. If you need to create a List:** In order to return a List you should create a List of Clientes in advance. In the while loop, firstly initialize a new Cliente object, then use set method to set the attributes for that object. Finally add the recently created object to the List.
**2. If not:** Replace the request.setAttribute by using PrintWriter. You can look up [here](https://www.oxxus.net/tutorials/servlet/servlet-stepbystep) for an example

```
final PrintWriter writerA = response.getWriter();
writerA.println("A1");
```